# How can I get the position of an element with jQuery after a successful Ajax Call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, lazy-loading, jquery-events

I am trying to create sort of a lazyloaded event with jQuery upon the container being scrolled to a certain position. This is supposed to happen after a successful ajax request, but I am having trouble getting the code to work here. Here is my code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: load.php,
    type: 'GET',
    cache: true,
    success: function(data) {
        $('#container').html(data)
    }
    });


$('#container').live('scroll', function() {  
var position = $("#load").offset().top;          
var scrollPosition = $('#container').height(); +$('#container').scrollTop();
if ( scrollPosition > position) {
     alert( "ALERT" );
                              }
});
```

Can anyone help me out here please. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: load.php,
    type: 'GET',
    cache: true,
    success: function(data) {
        $('#container').html(data);
    }
});


$('#container').live('scroll', function() {  
    var position = $("#load").offset().top;
    var scrollPosition = $('#container').height() + $('#container').scrollTop();
    if ( scrollPosition > position) {
        alert( "ALERT" );
    }
});
```

What did I change? Formatting mostly, but also removed an extra `;` after `$('#container').height()` ;-)

Comment: hahahah whoops, didnt catch that. lemme try it and ill get back in one second.

Comment: even with the fix it isn't producing any results.

Comment: in fact, i don't think it is getting the actual position of the element "load". When i change the function around to scrollPosition < position it should fire as soon as the container is scrolled, but it doesnt

Comment: It's a little hard when I don't understand exactly what you're trying to do, but is `#load` inside `#container`, and if so, is `position` supposed to be the top position of `#load` relative to `#container`? And does container scroll, or is it the whole document?

Comment: oh, sorry didnt see that last comment, yeah, the container is what scrolls, load is inside of the container. Its no worry, i just got it to work, i changed a couple of things, and the semicolon was a problem.